# Auto kill webthread in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am running apache tomcat on a server. From time to time single web-threads run longer than 1 minute. I would like to auto kill those.

Is there a tool for tomcat, which is able to kill a webthread-worker, if it is running longer than 60 seconds?

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html

Comment: are tomcat threads killed when the socket is closed?

Comment: Guess not, they should return to their thread pool.

Comment: the link you posted is for apache web server bridging to apache tomcat using jk. I use nginx upfront. My issue is that the web thread ist going crazy sometimes and needs to be killed if it is running too long. is this possible using configuration?